# Wrong format of a library in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

Below is my screen out of making:

```
gcc   bv3sdktest.o  libbv3sdk.a -o bv3sdktest
/usr/bin/ld: libbv3sdk.a(Bv3Sdk.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: libbv3sdk.a(Bv3Sdk.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: libbv3sdk.a(Bv3Sdk.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: libbv3sdk.a(Bv3Sdk.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: libbv3sdk.a(Bv3Sdk.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)
/usr/bin/ld: libbv3sdk.a(Bv3Sdk.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 40)

: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bv3sdktest] Error 1
```

I wonder what's wrong with it?

Comment: What does the command `file libbv3sdk.a` say?

Comment: What about `gcc bv3sdktest.o  -L . -l bv3sdk -o bv3sdktest`? That assumes that the library file is in the current dir. Please change `L . ` if required.

Comment: What's your target?

Comment: Below is my running result:

root@bv-iii-dev:/home/bviii/bv3/Bv3Sdk# file libbv3sdk.a 
libbv3sdk.a: current ar archive
root@bv-iii-dev:/home/bviii/bv3/Bv3Sdk# gcc bv3sdktest.o libv3sdk.a -o bv3sdktest
gcc: error: libv3sdk.a: No such file or directory

Comment: (continued)
root@bv-iii-dev:/home/bviii/bv3/Bv3Sdk# gcc bv3sdktest.o -L . -l bv3sdk -o bv3sdktest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libbv3sdk.a when searching for -lbv3sdk
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbv3sdk
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
root@bv-iii-dev:/home/bviii/bv3/Bv3Sdk# gcc bv3sdktest.o -L /home/bviii/bv3/Bv3Sdk/ -l bv3sdk -o bv3sdktest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/bviii/bv3/Bv3Sdk//libbv3sdk.a when searching for -lbv3sdk
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbv3sdk
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
root@bv-iii-dev:/home/bviii/bv3/Bv3Sdk#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. I compiled .o files in .a using $(CXX) which was for cross-compilation, but compiled main program's .o using gcc. No wonder the library can't be linked to main program. They have different target environment setting. I changed gcc to $(CXX) in compilation command of main program and link command, it works.